# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem not found

Tags: azure, docker

I am trying to dockerize my pyspark application to run on HDInsight Spark Cluster. For a simple job invoked from the docker, it throws the error:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.AzureBlobFileSystem not found;
```

I see this property is is set in the core-site.xml file on my HDInsight cluster. Where do I get this jar so I can install it on my docker as well? A basic google search did not return any results.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need hadoop-azure.jar from http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-azure/